# Clarification required about PrincipalContext security permissions and PrincipalContext's ContextType.Machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, active-directory, directoryservices, principalcontext

```
using (PrincipalContext Context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainURL, UserName, Password))
{
   UserPrincipal Account = new UserPrincipal(Context);
   Account.GivenName = strFirstName;
   Account.Surname = strLastName;

   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(Account);
   foreach (var principal in srch.FindAll())
     {
        var p = (UserPrincipal)principal;
        String FirstName = p.GivenName;
        String LastName = p.Surname;
     }            
}
```

If i use the code above to query Active Directory and the UserName(account) passed in the PrincipalContext constructor is in a domain that has no trust with the target domain(domain to be queried), i get the below error.

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException: The server could not be contacted. ---> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable.

Would i be correct to assume that if the PrincipalContext construct was changed to,

```
 using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
```

the code would execute successfully as long as the client is in the target domain?

Lets assume the first code with UserName and Password was called by a client in domain A trying to search for user info in domain B, here establishing context failed because the account used is in domain A that has no trust with domain B.

am i correct to assume that if i change the ContextType to Machine, and the client calling the code is in domain B, the code would execute succefully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that would not be a correct assumption. `ContextType.Machine` means that you want to work with local accounts.

Your `PrincipalSearcher` will end up searching the local SAM database rather than Active Directory